# C++ Dataflow Programming: Interconnecting Nodes With Differing Template Parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I don't really know exactly what my ideal solution will look like so please forgive any vagueness or improper terminology.

I'm working on a project that involves connecting nodes serially into a pipeline to process data from a hardware controller. On user input, the value will be pushed through the chain from node to node, in a dataflow programming style. Each node can have distinct input and output types, so what starts off as an int may end up producing a user-defined type by the end of the pipeline, or no type at all (just a function call without arguments). In terms of passing data through the pipeline, I've opted to implement things as a series of functors, so there's some degree of type erasure when it comes to handing data from node to node. Each Functor just processes its arguments and hands them to the next Functor in line.

The problem is changing the layout of the nodes or adding or subtracting them. I'm stumped on how to hold these mappings of different types and still be able to link them together without having to do a bunch of ugly and expensive dynamic_cast if statements. They all derive from a common class template, but their actual types are different depending on input/output parameters. I've split the interface up into input and output halves, so a receiving node can store a pointer to its source node type without having to know that node's input type(s) and all the nodes that came before it.

```
class IMapping 
{
    virtual void Enable() = 0;
    virtual void Disable() = 0;
    ...
}


template <typename InputT>
class IMapping_Inlet
{
public:

    virtual void SetSource(IMapping_Outlet<InputT> *pSource) { /* Stores pointer to new source */ };
    virtual IFunctor<InputT> GetFunc() = 0; // IFunctor<T> is just an alias for std::function<void(T)> for now.
    ...

protected:

    void SetFunc(IFunctor<InputT> *pFunc){ m_Func = pFunc; }; // Called from the derived class to set the function that processes InputT

    IMapping_Outlet<InputT> *m_Source;
    IFunctor<InputT> *m_Func;
}


template <typename OutputT>
class IMapping_Outlet
{
public:

    virtual void SetTarget(IMapping_Inlet<OutputT> *pTarget) { /* Stores pointer and calls pTarget->GetFunc() */ };

    virtual void SetFunc(IFunctor<OutputT> *pFunc) { /* Some mappings may want to swap out their functor */ };
    ...

protected:

    IMapping_Inlet<OutputT> *m_Target;
    IFunctor<OutputT> *m_TargetFunc;
}


template <typename InputT, OutputT>
class IMapping : public IMapping, public IMapping_Inlet<InputT>, public IMapping_Outlet<OutputT>
{
public:

    virtual void Init() { /* Derived type creates a functor (probably pointing to one of its own member functions) and passes it to IMapping_Inlet::SetFunc() */ };
    ...

}


class MyDerivedMapping : public IMapping<int, bool>
{
    void Init() override
    {   // Haven't tested this yet 
        IMapping_Inlet<int>::SetFunc(
            [auto tail = m_Target->GetFunc()] (int i) {
                bool b = i > 10 ? true : false;
                tail(b);
            }
        );
    };
}
```

So assuming you know the type of two nodes, and their input/output types match, you can map them together easily. But the enclosing pipeline class can't store all the nodes in a generic collection and still be able to map them together based  on concrete type. It would be nice if we had virtual template functions, because I could just define a templated SetSource/SetTarget function in the IMapping interface and dispatch based on the template parameter.

I was thinking I could template the Pipeline based on its input and output types, and let the mapping nodes do whatever they please in between. The Pipeline should only care if it's input type matches that of the first node, and its output type matches that of the last node.

I've been reading about TMP, CRTP, SFINAE, covariant return types, etc. but most of this is new material and over my head. This feels like it'd be in the domain of functional programming but I'm too inexperienced to understand how I'd practically use a functional approach that bridges the gap between run time and compile time.

As an example of something I'd want to do:
Let `[T, U]` denote an `IMapping<T, U>`, that is a mapping taking T as its input and passing U as its output.
I have nodes `[int, bool]->[bool, int]` and want to insert them into a longer string of nodes `[int, int]->[int, double]->[double, double]` after the first node.

I'd like to be able to interrogate the input or output types of a node from a base class pointer and downcast and map if the types are compatible.

Some of the tricks I've been reading about in Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Design seem like they could lend themselves to this scenario, but the sticking point is doing some of the decision-making at run time. Passing pointers into template functions that infer their type and then do some meta-programming magic would be great, but I think it would choose a template specialization based on the baseclass pointer not the derived type. Is there some way to implement an identity function in the base class that will return a covariant return type based on the derived template class?

CRTP seemed like a cool way to get around the virtual template function issue, but I'd still need to know the derived type when storing the Base pointer. I could inherit from a non-template base class, but then we're back at square one. It feels like this hurdle would inhibit a policy based design approach. How can you compose an object from several policies if it doesn't maintain a common interface among types with different policies. Each concrete type will have differing template arguments. It would work fine inheriting from a base class if all you needed to do  was invoke some side-effects via a simple function call, but anything more advanced than that seems impractical.

I'm just a bit confused as to how to tackle this type of architecture without sacrificing run time efficiency, future extensibility, and some degree of type safety. It doesn't seem like there's an easy solution in the classic vanilla c++ paradigm of yore, and I just don't know enough about template trickery and functional approaches to know where to start looking or what to search for.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction or suggest an approach.

Comment: Why are pipelines a different type than your functors?  What kind of changes do you need to do at runtime, *exactly*?  (Not pie in sky, but actual use cases)  Why does a node have to know about its predicessor at all?  Or its successor?  Someone has to, but why the node itself?

Comment: Pipelines represent a stream of single input/output connections between junctions, which can have multiple simultaneous inputs or outputs (not just multiple parameters per function call, but multiple sources or destinations) The reason for the distinction between single in/out vs multi is to allow deactivating a whole string of nodes at once by simply disabling the head node instead of iterating over the list. Multi In/Out needs to stop and inspect whether it still has any other input or output pipelines active and the junction can choose to propagate the deactivation up or downstream.

Comment: The nodes don't have to know about their neighbors per se, but a linked list seemed like it'd be the most flexible for insertions. It wouldn't require explicit coding of all the node input and output types. The pipeline could hold a pointer to the head node and have a function for iterating over the tail. I was thinking I'd need to use something like the visitor pattern to get them down to their derived interface (or at least to Mapping<T, U>) so they can exchange functors. That could be mediated by a 3rd party, but it would also need to be parameterized by <T, U>

Comment: If you want static type safety, erasing beyond IO types is not possible.  If you want dynamic type safety, you need to have failure points, and at those failure points dynamically cast (or equivalent).  If you don't want dynamic type safety, you still will want failure points, and at those points blindly cast with debug-time asserts.  With a complex system, I'd be tempted to make it functional and stateless beyond memoization, and split the graph problem (conditional disabling) from the evaluation problem.  But that is just me.

Comment: Changes at runtime would be mostly just swapping out other mappings on the fly to build custom chains of processing modules. These mappings will be things like scalar operators to +-*/ the input by a constant or variable value, logic operators for boolean inputs, conversion of int to bool once input increases above a threshold, filters to edit streams of input data, etc. The user will pick from a library of nodes to patch together, starting from their hardware inputs (knobs, buttons, keyboard input, other MIDI data) and ending with a call to the host program API.

Comment: I'm trying to somehow keep static type safety by avoiding storing them all in a heterogeneous container and instead having them communicate recursively sort of like a typelist. I could just have everything be properly immutable and destruct and reconstruct the whole chain of nodes again each time an insertion or removal occurs. Then I could bake in a typelist because the whole series of types would be known, and I could index into the list and retrieve the corresponding node types in order to display a list of compatible modules that could be inserted.

Comment: You’re basically saying that you need a `QVariant` type, and a metatype machinery that powers it. Depending on your licensing needs, you may be able to rip that part of Qt out and and use it for your project. `QVariant` stores “small” types unboxed, i.e. anything that fits in the larger of `void*` and `double`, with no stricter alignment, will be held inside the variant value – otherwise it’ll get dynamically allocated. This type has next to no overhead over scalar types, and does everything you want. A simple template can adapt a call with a vector of variants to a call with basic types.

Answer (score 4):

I've developed a modern C++ flow-based programming library called [DSPatch](http://flowbasedprogramming.com) that sports an object-oriented API very much like the one you've described. The class I think you'll find most interesting is the [RunType](https://github.com/MarcusTomlinson/DSPatch/blob/85ebd178576ad1b1964c7e44ab451aaf13151983/include/dspatch/RunType.h) class - used to carry data to and from components.

The [RunType](https://github.com/MarcusTomlinson/DSPatch/blob/85ebd178576ad1b1964c7e44ab451aaf13151983/include/dspatch/RunType.h) class makes use of an internal template class and public template methods to allow users to get and set the contained variable as any type they wish. Because the contained variable is templated internally, it has the ability to change type at run-time.

Now, to avoid as much overhead as possible during get / set, I use typeid() just once upon a type change, then cache the type for subsequent get / set type matching - see RunType::CopyFrom(). And in the case of a value move rather than copy, we don't need to match types at all - see RunType::MoveTo().

Wherever possible, data between components in [DSPatch](http://flowbasedprogramming.com) is transferred via move rather than copy.

Hope this helps!